# Upload to S3 via shell script without aws-cli, possible?

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

As the title says, is it possible to upload to S3 via shell script without aws-cli-tools?

If so, how?

What I'm trying to do is read from a txt file on S3 (which is public, so no authentication is required).

But I want to be able to overwrite whatever is in the file (which is just a number).

Thanks in advance,

Fadi

Comment: To clarify, I have **one** folder in my bucket that's available to public where the text file is located at.

Comment: You can use this library for managing objects on AWS S3 using shell scripts.
https://github.com/aishwarydhare/universal-docs-manager
It is pure shell script based objects manager which currently supports Local Disk, MySQL and AWS S3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can! You basically emulate the api calls the SDK would do for you through standard linux cmd utils.

Look at:

https://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-S3/943

and/or

http://tmont.com/blargh/2014/1/uploading-to-s3-in-bash

Comment: The second link is something that looks like it's going to work out great for me. Thanks again

Comment: yeah. IIRC that's sigv3. you can find sigv4 examples but the signing is more complicated

Comment: here is also a sigv4 example: https://gist.github.com/vszakats/2917d28a951844ab80b1

Comment: Thanks a bunch for posting this! The second link was definitely a life saver. I couldn't accept and settle to the idea of installing the fat AWS CLI for a simple s3 upload.

Comment: Secound example is working.Thanks for share this important document :)

Answer (score 5):

I use `s3cmd` which is a command line tool written in Python.

It uses the (restful) web APIs.

- `s3cmd put --recursive`
- `s3cmd sync`

would be the interesting bits:

> Synchronize a directory tree to S3
>
> s3cmd sync LOCAL_DIR s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX] or s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX] LOCAL_DIR